# Conflict between OpenCV and pcl library in CPP

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl-es

```
objc[5267]: Class vtkCocoaTimer is implemented in both /usr/local/opt/vtk/lib/libvtkRenderingUI-9.0.1.dylib (0x11bceb438) and /usr/local/opt/vtk@8.2/lib/libvtkRenderingOpenGL2-8.2.1.dylib (0x1100d5e90). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[5267]: Class vtkCocoaFullScreenWindow is implemented in both /usr/local/opt/vtk@8.2/lib/libvtkRenderingOpenGL2-8.2.1.dylib (0x1100d5f08) and /usr/local/opt/vtk/lib/libvtkRenderingOpenGL2-9.0.1.dylib (0x11bc07240). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[5267]: Class vtkCocoaServer is implemented in both /usr/local/opt/vtk@8.2/lib/libvtkRenderingOpenGL2-8.2.1.dylib (0x1100d5f30) and /usr/local/opt/vtk/lib/libvtkRenderingOpenGL2-9.0.1.dylib (0x11bc07268). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[5267]: Class vtkCocoaGLView is implemented in both /usr/local/opt/vtk@8.2/lib/libvtkRenderingOpenGL2-8.2.1.dylib (0x1100d5f80) and /usr/local/opt/vtk/lib/libvtkRenderingOpenGL2-9.0.1.dylib (0x11bc072b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
zsh: segmentation fault  ./stereo
```

When I am using opencv and pcl lib in my C++ code it's building successfully but while executing I was getting this error with vtk. In my system pcl is using vtk@8.2 and opencv using vtk@9.0. I tried removing one version of vtk but then it's not building So how to fix this?

Comment: it looks like some project configuration issue where you link both against an alias and actual library or you have two libvtk version installed and linked..

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the multiple vtk versions. while running the opengl is called more than once by opencv and pcl which leds to a include loop. To solve this we have to turn off vtk form the dependencies of OpenCV while building it.